# Spaces disappearing in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Take a look in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/a7bUx/

I have created 2 `textarea`s with different CSS settings using `.val`. I then set 2 `textarea`s to the same value, both with 4 spaces in the front. However, The one with the CSS settings seems to "removed" those spaces. Why?

I don't think `white-space: nowrap;` would have any affect on this, because even you press Ctrl+A to select all and paste it to a text processor the spaces are still missing.

[image]

I tested on Chrome and another Webkit-based browser. Same result.

Comment: What browser are you using? No issues on Firefox. I get four spaces in front of the text in both `textarea`s.

Comment: Am also tried. Both having spaces. Am using firefox.

Comment: Chrome is the issue indeed.

Comment: And I do get your issue on Chrome!

Comment: Removing `white-space: nowrap;` works for Chrome.

Comment: Is this a bug in Webkit?

Comment: No, it's actually how [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) should work according to MDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `whitespace: no-wrap;`

Try using

```
white-space: pre;
```

Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks Acts like the `<pre>` tag in HTML.

**Updates:**

From your comments, you should go with `wrap="off"` attribute.

Also would like you to go through [**Textarea Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/) and refer

> **Nowrap section:**
>
> > To prevent text from wrapping normally in CSS, you use ***`white-space:
> >     nowrap`***.  *But for whatever reason, that doesn't work with textareas.
> >     If you want to be able to type into textareas and would rather lines
> >     do not break until you press return/enter (a horizontal scrollbar is
> >     triggered instead)*, ***you'll have to use the wrap="off" attribute***.

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a7bUx/5/)

Comment: I just tested it. In Chrome if you use `pre` the text will still wrap.

Comment: @user1671639 - No, what I meant is I don't want the text to wrap. I want it to go all the way to the right until it hits a newline. But I tested in Chrome both `pre` and `pre-wrap` will wrap the text to the next line even I didn't insert a newline. Any idea why?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Sorry for that. But `pre` belongs to no-wrap. check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: @user1671639 - I know it is in the `no-wrap` category, but in Chrome it is still wrapping like in `normal` and I need a fix for it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Then you should use `wrap="off"` attribute

Comment: @user1671639 - Ohhh I didn't know there is a `wrap` attribute. Thanks!

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `white-space: nowrap;`
check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7bUx/3/) in chrome. this will work

You can use `javscript` and `regular expression` for `removing trailing white spaces`.
Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7bUx/4/) . I think this will help you

Comment: Thanks but what do removing trailing white spaces have to do with my question?

Answer (score 1):

According to this article from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/):

> Notice in HTML code example at the top of this article, there are
>   actually two line breaks, one before the line of text and one after,
>   which allow the text to be on it's own line (in the code). When the
>   text renders in the browser, those line breaks appear as if they are
>   stripped out. Also stripped out are the extra spaces one the line
>   before the first letter. If we want to force the browser to display
>   those line breaks and extra white space characters we can use
>   white-space: pre;

So, `white-space: pre` will keep the whitespace.

Also from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.